# how to deal with changing DOCUMENT_ROOT in an html website

Tags: php, html

I am a newbie to web development and I am trying to learn best practices as I go along.
I code and run my website locally using Dreamweaver on a local Apache server; Then I deploy it remotely and I test it there.
I use for my website (html, php and some js).

I have been facing an issue since I started this and I don't know any good practices to resolve it.

DOCUMENT_ROOT is a php variable that changes; Locally it points to xampp/htdocs (and not my actual website root xampp/htdocs/myWebsite) and remotely it points to my actual document root.

So right now I can't use this for the above reason so I end up locating files using the absolute path on the remote server.

Is there a good practice to avoid this?

PS:

- I know I can change php.ini config file to change where DOCUMENT_ROOT points to but I don't want either..
- Also, I can't hard code relative paths (as commentators have suggested) because I have a scripts running from different directories... So I can't hard code relative paths there

Comment: For what reason do you need to know the doc root?  Just use relative paths wherever possible.

Comment: if you have a variable path then use a site specific include file in conjuction with DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: because I have a scripts running from different directories... So I can't hard code relative paths there

Comment: be consistent is a good design approach

Comment: @Kam You can. Make use of the `__DIR__` constant

Comment: You can define a constant in your main script that all other scripts include; something like `define('PROJECT_DIR', __DIR__)`. That's what I do.

Comment: @Mark you are saying that for this to work I just change PROJECT_DIR everytime I switch targets?

Comment: @Kam: Huh? Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. All your files should be relative to *something*. That's usually your project folder. If you've got some 3rd party scripts included in various places then you're going to have to update your PHP include paths for each server, or have one non-version controlled server-config file that holds all the proper paths. Or use environment variables.

Comment: @MArk Maybe I wasn't clear. I have an image in Document_root/images/m1.jpg and I have a script that refers to it using relative path. then if that script is included in other php scripts in different directories the relative path would not work.

Comment: @Kam: That's why you define `PROJECT_DIR` constant in *one* place (some sort of config file) and include it where-ever you need to use it. It won't change regardless of where you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to go about it. Create a configuration file and determine if the site is running on a local site or live site, then include that configuration file on each page.  You can also set settings like error reporting and database connections for each this way.

```
//Determine if Server is local system or live site
    if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'local')||(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)=='192.168')){
        $local=TRUE;
    }

    else {
        $local=FALSE;
    }

if($local){
    define('BASE_URL','http://localhost/localsite/');
    define('BASE_URI','C:/localserver/htdocs/localsite/');
}
else{
    define('BASE_URL','http://www.example.com/');
    define('BASE_URI','server/directory/pathToRoot/');
    }
```

Then you can use the defined constants in your php pages to define your paths. For example:

```
include(BASE_URI.'directory/filename.php');
<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>directory/filename.html">Some Link</a>
```

And it will work correctly on each deployment.

Comment: Using a front controller is preferable over including the configuration file in every page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. A front controller is not something I have done yet, but now I will look into it.